# how value returned from jquery can be used as a php variable

Tags: php, jquery

```js
   var a;
   function getdatafromddl(){
    a = document.getElementById("payflag").value;
    location.href="?a="+a;
   }

   $(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedRow;
    var record;
    
    $('tr').click(function () {
     $('tr').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
     selectedRow = $(this);
    });

    $('#viewbtn').click(function() {
     var td = $(selectedRow).children('td');
     //alert(td[0].innerText);
     var value = td[0].innerText;
     //$('#order').val(value); 
     
     $.post('pickorderno.php',{value:value}, function(response){
      $('#order').val(response); 
      //alert(response);
     });
    });
   });
```

```css
.centr-div { margin:0px auto; background-color:#fff; width:92%; height:500px}

.f-col{ float:left; width:50%; height:36px; margin-top:14px; background-color: #fff }
.s-col{ float:left; width:25%; height:40px; margin-top:10px; background-color: #fff }
.l-col{ float:left; width:25%; height:40px; margin-top:10px; background-color: #fff }

.spc{ float:left; width:100%; height:15px; background-color: #F4F4F4 }

#statdd { float:right; font-family:verdana; font-size:10pt; }

.pay { width:60%; height:20pt; font-family:verdana; font-size:10pt; }

#show-recs{ border-collapse: collapse; }

table { width: 98%; }

th{ width:20%; height: 12px; font-family:Arial; font-size: 12pt; border-bottom: 1px solid #ECEBEB; color: #960001 }

td { border-bottom: 1px solid #ECEBEB; }

tr { height: 25px; text-align: center; color: #0000BD }

.selected { background-color: #80FFFF; }

.showViewbtn{ width:25%; height: 25px; color:#0000FF; text-decoration:none; background-color:#fff; font-family:verdana; font-size:10pt }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div align="center">
    <img src="images/menu.jpg" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="centr-div">
    <div class="f-col"> <label id="statdd">Show orders on basis of&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="s-col">
     <select id="payflag" onchange="getdatafromddl()" class="pay">
      <option value = "-1">---- Selection ----</option>
      <option value = "Paid" <?php if($_GET['a'] == 'Paid') echo "selected"; ?> >Paid</option>
      <option value = "Un-Paid" <?php if($_GET['a'] == 'Un-Paid') echo "selected"; ?> >Un-Paid</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="l-col">
     <input type="text" id="order" name="txtorder" value="" />
    </div>
  <!-- *******   Table - 1   ***********  -->
    <?php
     if (isset($_GET['a'])) {
       $val = $_GET['a'];
     }
     if(!empty($val)){
      if ($val == 'Un-Paid')
      {
       $getrecs = "SELECT u.t_ordid, DATE_FORMAT(u.tord_dt,'%d-%m-%Y') as label_date, c.u_name, s.stat_desc  FROM utmp_orders as u join user_dtls as c on c.user_id=u.user_id join status as s on s.stat_cd=u.stat_cd WHERE u.pay_flag='N'";
       $retrv = mysqli_query($connection, $getrecs);
       }else if ($val == 'Paid') {
       $getrecs = "SELECT u.t_ordid, DATE_FORMAT(u.tord_dt,'%d-%m-%Y') as label_date, c.u_name, s.stat_desc  FROM utmp_orders as u join user_dtls as c on c.user_id=u.user_id join status as s on s.stat_cd=u.stat_cd WHERE u.pay_flag='Y'";
       $retrv = mysqli_query($connection, $getrecs);
      }
      else{ $retrv="";}
     }
    ?>
    <table id='show-recs'>
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Order No.</th>
       <th>Order Dt.</th>
       <th>Client Name</th>
       <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
      <?php 
       if (!empty($retrv)){
       while($retrvarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retrv)){ 
      ?>
       <tbody> 
        <tr>
         <td><?php echo $retrvarr["t_ordid"] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $retrvarr["label_date"] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $retrvarr["u_name"] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $retrvarr["stat_desc"] ?></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <div class="spc"></div> 
    <div align="center"><input type="submit" id="viewbtn" class="showViewbtn" value="View Selected Record" /></div>
    <div class="spc"></div>
  <!-- *****   Table - 2   *************  -->
    <?php
     //$ono=null;
     $ono = isset($_POST['txtorder']) ? $_POST['txtorder'] : null;
     echo 'VAL :'.$ono; 
    
     //$ono = 2;
     if(!empty($ono)){
      $selrec_query = "SELECT u.file_path, u.lbl_qty, u.lbl_prc, s.scat_name FROM utmp_orders as u join subcategory as s on s.scat_id = u.scat_id where u.t_ordid = {$ono}";
      $result = mysqli_query($connection, $selrec_query);
     } 
    ?>

    <table id='show-sel-recs'>
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Label Image</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Price (&pound;)</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Payment Recd</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <?php 
       if (!empty($result)){
       while($resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
      ?>
        <tbody> 
         <tr>
          <td><img src="<?php echo $resultarr['file_path'] ?>" alt="" style="width:61px; height:54px" /></td>
          <td><?php echo $resultarr["lbl_qty"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $resultarr["lbl_prc"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $resultarr["scat_name"] ?></td>
          <td></td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       <?php }} ?>
    </table>

   </div>
```

***Please check the code in "display.php" shown withing [ Line no .. ]***

The full code is in **display.php**. I am also attaching the screenshot of the page "output.jpg", I am having problems with.

Here what I am trying to accomplish :

First the user will select item from Drop down. Then on the basis of selected item, Table-1 gets filled up.
Then when the user clicks on any row of the first table, order no is picked up thereby displaying other details of the order in the second table.

I don't have any problem in the first table.  Problem comes when the user clicks on a row of the first table. Order number do gets picked up [ line no 18 to 33 ] and is shown in the text box using the syntax "$('#order').val(response)" [ Line no. 31 ].

I have taken a textbox to store the value of the jquery variable in the textbox. Once this is done next step would be to run sql query on the basis of selected record which is in the text box that will fill the second table accordingly.

But when I try to retrieve the value of the textbox using $_POST['txtorder'], nothing is shown. WHY [ Please check line no. 101 to 105 ]

**display.php**

```
    1.<?php include ("dbcon.php"); ?>
2.
3.<!DOCTYPE html>
4. <html>
5.  <head>
6.   <title></title>
7.   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="workstyle.css">
8.   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
9.   <script>
10. var a;
11. function getdatafromddl(){
12.           a = document.getElementById("payflag").value;
13.           location.href="?a="+a;
14. }
15.   </script>
16.
17.   <script>
18. $(document).ready(function() {
19.           var selectedRow;
20.           var record;
21.           $('tr').click(function () {
22.               $('tr').removeClass('selected');
23.        $(this).addClass('selected');
24.        selectedRow = $(this);
25.           });
26.
27.           $('#viewbtn').click(function() {
28.       var td = $(selectedRow).children('td');
29.       var value = td[0].innerText;
30.       $.post('pickorderno.php',{value:value}, function(response){
31.                $('#order').val(response); 
32.       });
33.           });
34. });
35.   </script>
36.  </head>
37.
38.  <body>
39.    <div align="center">
40.      <img src="images/menu.jpg" alt="" />
41.    </div>
42.    <div class="centr-div">
43.
44.    <div class="f-col"> <label id="statdd">Show orders on basis of&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
45.    <div class="s-col">
46.      <select id="payflag" onchange="getdatafromddl()" class="pay">
47.        <option value = "-1">---- Selection ----</option>
48.        <option value = "Paid" <?php if($_GET['a'] == 'Paid') echo "selected"; ?> >Paid</option>
49.        <option value = "Un-Paid" <?php if($_GET['a'] == 'Un-Paid') echo "selected"; ?> >Un-Paid</option>
50.      </select>
51.    </div>
52.    <div class="l-col"> <input type="text" id="order" name="txtorder" value="" /> </div>
53.
54.    <!-- ********   Table - 1   ********  -->
55.
56.    <?php
57. if (isset($_GET['a'])) {
58.   $val = $_GET['a'];
59. }
60. if(!empty($val)){
61.          if ($val == 'Un-Paid')
62.          {
63.          $getrecs = "SELECT u.t_ordid, DATE_FORMAT(u.tord_dt,'%d-%m-%Y') as label_date, c.u_name, s.stat_desc  FROM utmp_orders as u join user_dtls as c on c.user_id=u.user_id join status as s on s.stat_cd=u.stat_cd WHERE u.pay_flag='N'";
64.      $retrv = mysqli_query($connection, $getrecs);
65.   }else if ($val == 'Paid') {
66.      $getrecs = "SELECT u.t_ordid, DATE_FORMAT(u.tord_dt,'%d-%m-%Y') as label_date, c.u_name, s.stat_desc  FROM utmp_orders as u join user_dtls as c on c.user_id=u.user_id join status as s on s.stat_cd=u.stat_cd WHERE u.pay_flag='Y'";
67.      $retrv = mysqli_query($connection, $getrecs);
68.          }
69.        else{ $retrv="";}
70. }
71.    ?>
72.    <table id='show-recs'>
73. <thead>
74.   <tr>
75.     <th>Order No.</th>
76.     <th>Order Dt.</th>
77.     <th>Client Name</th>
78.     <th>Status</th>
79.          </tr>
80. </thead>
81.        <?php 
82. if (!empty($retrv)){
83.   while($retrvarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retrv)){ 
84.        ?>
85.     <tbody> 
86.          <tr>
87.     <td><?php echo $retrvarr["t_ordid"] ?></td>
88.     <td><?php echo $retrvarr["label_date"] ?></td>
89.     <td><?php echo $retrvarr["u_name"] ?></td>
90.     <td><?php echo $retrvarr["stat_desc"] ?></td>
91.          </tr>
92. </tbody>
93.        <?php }} ?>
94.    </table>
95.    <div class="spc"></div>  
96.    <div align="center"><input type="submit" id="viewbtn" class="showViewbtn" value="View Selected Record" /></div>
97.    <div class="spc"></div>
98.
99.<!-- *********   Table - 2   ************  -->
100.    <?php
101.    //$ono=null;
102.    $ono = isset($_POST['txtorder']) ? $_POST['txtorder'] : null;
103.    //$ono = $('#order').attr('value');
104.    
105.    echo 'VAL :'.$ono;  
106.
107.    //$ono = 2;
108.    if(!empty($ono)){
109.          $selrec_query = "SELECT u.file_path, u.lbl_qty, u.lbl_prc, s.scat_name FROM utmp_orders as u join subcategory as s on s.scat_id = u.scat_id where u.t_ordid = {$ono}";
110.          $result = mysqli_query($connection, $selrec_query);
111.    }   
112.    ?>
113.
114.    <table id='show-sel-recs'>
115.      <thead>
116.    <tr>
117.          <th>Label Image</th>
118.          <th>Qty</th>
119.          <th>Price (&pound;)</th>
120.          <th>Category</th>
121.          <th>Payment Recd</th>
122.    </tr>
123.      </thead>
124.      <?php 
125.        if (!empty($result)){
126.       while($resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
127.      ?>
128.           <tbody>  
129.          <tr>
130.                <td><img src="<?php echo $resultarr['file_path'] ?>" alt="" style="width:61px; height:54px" /></td>
131.                <td><?php echo $resultarr["lbl_qty"] ?></td>
132.                <td><?php echo $resultarr["lbl_prc"] ?></td>
133.                <td><?php echo $resultarr["scat_name"] ?></td>
134.                <td></td>
135.          </tr>
136.           </tbody>
137.      <?php } ?>
138.    </table>
139.   </div>
140.  </body>
141.</html>
142.<?php //get_footer(); ?>
```

**pickorderno.php**

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['value'])){
        $rethtml = $_POST['value'];
    }
    else {
        $rethtml = 'Invalid Data';
    }
    echo $rethtml;
?>
```

Sorry Image is not uploading [Error : You need atleast 10 reputation to post images]

Comment: could you provide a fiddle mate.

Comment: What @Outlooker means, Suneet, is that it would help people on SO help you if you could break your problem down to the core of what is going wrong, and put up an example of it in http://jsfiddle.net/ so that other people can look at it in a live environment, understand it, and fix it to help you. As it is, it's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do and most people won't want to read through many lines of code to find the bit that's causing you problems. Edit your answer to improve your chances of getting help :-)

Comment: Do not radically edit away all the content of the question.

Comment: might be more useful to show the html output rather then the php, as that's what your js will run against

Comment: I've posted an answer but it seems that the title of the topic is not really related to the description. Connecting to the DB is another topic :/

Comment: No I don't meant by that. I was saying my site was a dynamic one, so how will i show my code using "jsfiddle.net" as things will not be shown on the page correctly without a database connection.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is lacking of details but let's try to give you one correct way to do it.

1) PHP runs on server side and not client side

2) jQuery runs on the client side and not on the server side

Thus... I would suggest you to create the container with PHP (with an ID or class depending of what you need). Then use jQuery to inject your value.

Create a container in PHP with an ID

```
<?php echo "<div id='container'>placeholder</div>"; ?>
```

**OR**

```
?><div id='container'>placeholder</div><?php
```

Create a container in PHP with an ID

```
$("#container").val("My new value");
```

or you could use this but not recommended

```
$("#container").val("<?php echo 'your value'; ?>")
```